# Правила инкапсуляции С#

Tags: c#, winforms

Маленький вопрос об общих правилах написания кода. Работаю я с шаблоном MVC в WinForms.
В классе ViewDetailed:View в целях выполнения привязки у меня создана ссылка на класс FrmDetailed в виде поля. От этой проинициализированной ссылки вызываются элементы управления формы.

```
public ViewDetailed(Model model, Controller controller, FrmDetailed f):base(model, controller) 
        {
            form = f;
        }
form.txtboxCpu.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", model.Cpu, "ActiveProcess"));
```

Элемент управления в этом случае представлен полем, созданным автоматически в частичном классе FrmDelailed.Designer. Для возможности вызова элемента управления в классе представления поначалу я создал свойство для чтения:

```
public TextBox TxtboxCpu
        {
            get { return txtboxCpu; }
        }
```

Хотя проект компилировался и без этого. Может быть дело в том, что класс FrmDetailed частичный.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, с точки зрения правильности кода следует обращаться к свойству или к полю элемента управления? Да и вообще, считывть/записывать данные из полей, имеющих свойства, напрямую или всё-таки работать со свойствами, если они есть?

Comment: По-моему тут много раз подобные вопросы задавались, поищите. Свойство нужно, если вы хотите повесить какую-то логику на чтение и/или запись данных в поле. Ну и в целом это более правильно - чтобы снаружи не было публичного доступа к полям класса. Чтобы можно было поля класса читать-писать только через свойства или через методы.

Comment: MVC? В Winforms? Вы точно ничего не перепутали?

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: Да, в Winforms. Моделью представлена логика. Вид - привязки данных к элементам формы или обработчики. Контроллер помогает обрабатывать события элементов управления, запуская операции.

Comment: Быть может MVP был бы уместнее? MVC больше подходит для веба, где нет постоянной связи между UI и бэком, а данные передаются запросами.

Comment: Интересно. Спасибо.